# grep not consider dot in exact search

Tags: linux, awk, grep

It's possible to grep only exact match?

My file

```
# cat tlds.csv 
159,.COM,com.csv
862,.UK.COM,uk.com.csv
866,.US.COM,us.com.csv
```

My command in terminal

```
# cat tlds.csv | grep -i -w  'com.csv'
159,.COM,com.csv
862,.UK.COM,uk.com.csv
866,.US.COM,us.com.csv
```

required output 
**  159,.COM,com.csv**

I need only `com.csv` no other result. any way to get this done ?

Comment: Could you clearly what you expect? Do you want to get the whole 1 line as in the example or just the string com.csv as in the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
cat tlds.csv | grep -E ',com\.csv$'
```

In this way, you tell grep that you want only those lines that have a `,` before `com.csv`, and nothing more after `com.csv`.

You can also use

```
cat tlds.csv | grep -E '[^.]com\.csv$'
```

to tell grep that before `com.csv` it's okay any char except for `.`.
Anyway, if I can add a suggestion I wouldn't use `cat`. grep can take your file as an argument, int this way:

```
grep -E '[^.]com\.csv$' tlds.csv
```

[Here](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) you can see why you should prefer not using `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

This will print only those lines where the specific field you want to search in (the last one, i.e. `$NF` in awk) exactly matches the specific, literal string you want to find (i.e. `"com.csv"`):

```
$ awk -F, '$NF=="com.csv"' file
159,.COM,com.csv
```